# Android app blank screen after Facebook login on WebView

Tags: java, android

First of all I would like to say that I'm total noob when it comes to Android and Java development but I have managed to run the following code and it lauches my website. Sweet.

Here is the code:

```
package se.madesolutions.cmok;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;
private WebView mywebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mywebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = mywebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mywebView.loadUrl("http://mywebsite.com");

    mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());


    //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

   // FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mywebView.canGoBack()){
        mywebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.connect();
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://se.madesolutions.cmok/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://se.madesolutions.cmok/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
    client.disconnect();
}
}
```

What i have done is that I have implemented Facebook login on my website where users can login easy. This works great when I test on Desktop computer but when trying to login through the Android app which launches same website i'm just getting a blank webpage after login with Facebook.

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this? All help appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        mywebView.loadUrl("http://mywebsite.com");
```

Try This

Comment: Hi bud.. i have just writen entire code.. Could you add your code into mine.. I dont know where to paste your code.. sorry mate total noob here :(

Comment: You just want to load facebook.com via webview in your android app?? or you want to implement facebook login through your app??

Comment: No im loading my website through android app... On my website i have implemented a button to login to my website through facebook application.. So basicly i can open same webpage though webrowser.. The login works great with the webrowser but when I test same login through android app its just blank.

Comment: you are not able to load your page on you phone via your application.. when you run app the screen is blank right??

Comment: im able to load my webpage through the app.. It works fine.. But after clicking on the button "login with facebook" which i have on my website and where I enter my FB credentials that is when the page becomes blank, after the login to FB.

Comment: add above code after webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); and remove lines mywebView.loadUrl("http://mywebsite.com");

    mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

Answer (score 0):

hi i have same problem and i have solved.This happened due to loading your activity.May be you used some background with heavy images.

Try this way

Add this theme in your manifest file that white screen activity

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

Thanks hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

@mansur try using facebook Sdk which is very easy to login and fetch data from facebook related to that user